# How can I split items in a txt in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text

I have the following code in a text file:

```
Host: 0.0.0.0 Port: 80
```

This is my python code:

```
with open('config.txt', 'r') as configfile:
    lines = configfile.readlines()
    lines.split(': ')
    HOST = lines[1]
    PORT = lines[3]

print(f'Your host is {HOST} and port is {PORT}')
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    lines.split(': ')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can I fix this? I'm fairly new to python

Comment: There are two issues, 1) `lines.split(':')`, returns a new object use `lines = lines.split(': ')`. 2) The `readlines()` returns a list of all lines. You can use `for lines in configfile.readlines():` or `for lines in configfile:` to get the values one by one.

Comment: What is your desired output? If you split that example, (fixing the other issue you have) you will get `'Your host is 0.0.0.0 Port and port is 80'`

Comment: next time first use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- `readlines()` return a list of all the lines in the file
- `split` returns a list, it's not an in-place operation

```
with open('config.txt', 'r') as configfile:
    lines = configfile.readlines() # lines will be a list of all the lines in the file
    line_split = lines[0].split(': ') # split returns a list, it's not an in-place operation
    print(line_split)
    HOST = line_split[1].split()[0]
    PORT = line_split[2]

print(f'Your host is {HOST} and port is {PORT}')
```

Answer (score 1):

The readlines() method returns a list. You can't do a split on an entire list.

You should do something along the lines of the below, you may not need the for loop if there's not multiple lines in the text file. But, you will likely need it to read the entire text file.

```
with open('config.txt', 'r') as configfile:
    lines = configfile.readlines()
    for item in lines:
        item.split(': ')
        HOST = item[1]
        PORT = item[3]

        print(f'Your host is {HOST} and port is {PORT}')
```

You could also use the range function if you need to index different list strings

```
with open('config.txt', 'r') as configfile:
    lines = configfile.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines):
        split_string = lines[i].split(': ')
        HOST = split_string [1]
        PORT = split_string [3]

        print(f'Your host is {HOST} and port is {PORT}')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple fix:**

1. You need to use `readline()` instead of `readlines()`
2. You need to reassign the lines variable after splitting as `lines = lines.split(": ")`

**Reason:**

1. `readline()` returns a line from our file in the form of a string
2. `readlines()` returns all the lines from our file in the form of
   list/array of strings
3. split method is not inplace and it returns
   the list of strings and hence we need to reassign our `lines` variable
   with the returned result.

**Fixed Code:**

```
with open('config.txt', 'r') as configfile:
    lines = configfile.readline()
    lines = lines.split(': ')
    HOST = lines[1].split()[0]
    PORT = lines[2]

print("Your host is {HOST} and port is {PORT}".format(HOST = HOST, PORT = PORT))
```

Config.txt:

```
Host: 0.0.0.0 Port: 80
```

Output:

```
Your host is 0.0.0.0 and port is 80
```